# How to write a template function that adds an object of variant class type to a vector?

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, vector

I have another problem that I have no idea how to solve. Maybe somebody can help me.

What I want to do:
I have a vector that shall take elements of various class types. In my example code I have two classes (Line, circle) that are both derived from a virtual class segment.
My code shall chain several circle or Line elements and put them in the vector. Each element may be different from the other (different radii, different starting and ending points, etc) and the sequence of elements shall vary from execution to execution. That is for instance for the first execution I have a circle with radius 2 followed by another circle of radius 1, followed by a Line of length 4 and for the second execution I have a Line of length 1 followed by another Line of Length 5 in a different direction, followed by a circle of radius 0.5.

I've already learned how to compose the vector such that it can contain different types but as of now the sequence and definition of each element is hard-coded. Now I want to make this flexible (in the end the sequence and definition shall be file-driven). For this I attempt to implement a template function that takes whatever element is fed into it and adds it to the vector. The current definition also takes the vector as input but I may end up to define this function as a method for the vector.

Unfortunately I cannot figure out a way how to do it that works. I understand that I cannot copy a `unique_ptr` so I tried with the `std::move()` method but doesn't work. I get an C2664 error message of the xmemory module in line 671 saying that I cannot convert argument 1 in T2 into a std::nullptr_t.

Can somebody help me here? That'll be so awesome!

Here's my example code that implements the basic idea for my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <variant>


struct point
{
    double x;
    double y;
};

class segment
{
public:
    segment() 
    {
        P1.x = 0;
        P1.y = 0;

        P2.x = 0;
        P2.y = 0;
    };
    virtual ~segment() {};

    virtual double get_radius() { return 0; };
    virtual double get_length() { return 0; };
    virtual double get_angle() { return 0; };

    int segment_id = 0;

protected:
    point P1;
    point P2;
};

class Line : public segment
{
public:
    Line() {};
    Line(const point pt1, const point pt2)
    {
        P1.x = pt1.x;
        P1.y = pt1.y;

        P2.x = pt2.x;
        P2.y = pt2.y;

        segment_id = 1;
    };

    ~Line() {};

    double get_length() { return calc_length(); };
    double get_angle() { return calc_angle(); };

private:
    double calc_length()
    {
        // calculate length (here: dummy value)
        return 1;
    }

    double calc_angle()
    {
        // calculate angle (here: dummy value)
        return 0.5;
    }

    double length = 0;
    double angle = 0;
}
;

class circle : public segment
{
public:
    circle()
    {
        center.x = 0;
        center.y = 0;
    };
    circle(const double r, const point c)
    {
        radius = r;
        center.x = c.x;
        center.y = c.y;

        segment_id = 2;
    };

    ~circle() {};

    double get_radius() { return radius; };
    point get_center() { return center; };
    double get_length() { return 3.14 * radius; }; //returns circumference

private:
    double radius = 0;
    point center;
};

//-------------------------------------------------------
//T1: class type "segment", T2: class object Line or circle
template<typename T1, typename T2>
inline void add_segment(T1 v, T2 line_or_circle)
{
    v.emplace_back(line_or_circle);
}

//-------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    int nbr = 5;
    point start;
    start.x = 1;
    start.y = 2;

    point end;
    end.x = 3;
    end.y = 4;

    point c;
    c.x = 0;
    c.y = 0;

    double r = 9;

    auto anotherCircle = std::make_unique<circle>(r, c);
    auto anotherLine = std::make_unique<Line>(start, end);

    circle myCircle(r, c);
    
    //VERSION 1: Does now compile. 
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<segment>> v1;
    v1.emplace_back(std::move(anotherCircle));
    v1.emplace_back(std::move(anotherLine));
    std::cout << v1[0]->get_radius() << std::endl;
    std::cout << v1[1]->segment_id << std::endl;

    //VERSION 2: Compiles
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<segment>> v2;

    v2.emplace_back(std::make_unique<circle>(r, c));

    v2.emplace_back(std::make_unique<Line>(start, end));

    //=================================================================
    //now I want to implement this as a function call
    //=================================================================

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<segment>> v3;

    //VERSION 5:
    auto myLine2 = std::make_unique<Line>(start, end);
    add_segment(v3, std::move(myLine2)); //shall add object of class Line or circle (derived from virtual segment class, see above) to vector v3. In this example a Line but might be a circle

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `add_segment` is taking the vector by value. This fails to compile because the vector is uncopyable, as unique pointers are uncopyable. Even if you used a copyable pointer type, it would be a pointless method as the copy is destroyed at the end of the function.

You will also need to move the `line_or_circle` parameter in the body of `add_segment`.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
inline void add_segment(T1 & v, T2 line_or_circle)
{
    v.emplace_back(std::move(line_or_circle));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @Caleth! This is doing what I want to achieve. And thank you for pointing out my mistake with not referencing v.