# How can I copy a unique_ptr so it does not lose possession?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

My question is related to the proposed answer in [how to write a template function that adds an object of variant class type to a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66367777/how-to-write-a-template-function-that-adds-an-object-of-variant-class-type-to-a).

The suggested answer was fine and did exactly what I wanted to achieve but unfortunately it comes with some disadvantages.

Here is the code segment that calls the function (the entire code is in the link above):

```
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<segment>> v3;

    //VERSION 5:
    auto myLine2 = std::make_unique<Line>(start, end);
    add_segment(v3, std::move(myLine2)); //shall add object of class Line or circle (derived from virtual segment class, see above) to vector v3. In this example a Line but might be a circle
```

This is the template function as proposed and already implemented:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
inline void add_segment(T1 & v, T2 line_or_circle)
{
    v.emplace_back(std::move(line_or_circle));
}
```

Now what happens is - as far as I understand - that myLine2 loses the possession of the memory sections containing the data and I assume that it is then either pointing nowhere or is deleted. Now I may want to put the same pointer twice into the vector but for this I would have to create another pointer with the same data, e.g. `auto myLine3 = std::make_unique<Line>(start, end);` and feed it to the function. I've tried this and it works but I would by far prefer to just feed myLine2 again to the function.

I could not find if there is a sort copy function that in the background creates another pointer pointing to the memory section containing the data of myLine2 or - if unavoidable - a deep copy but that is deleted after leaving the scope of the function so that the possession of the memory for myLine2 is not lost. So instead of `std::move()` I could use this copy function.

Does somebody have an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Why do you use `std::unique_ptr` if you don't want unique ownership?

Comment: If, as it seems, you want shared ownership use a [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: "unique" and having more than one identical copies doesnt go well together

Comment: Ok! Thanks for these comments! I was thinking in the same direction but I was unsure if shared_ptr is save. I am no C++ expert but learning on the run and hence not fully familiar with these concepts. From what I've read in the net it seemed that shared_ptr should be avoided when possible. If I use ```std::shared_ptr``` do I also have to use ```std::move()```?

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` is somewhat more difficult to use that `unique_ptr`, because it's more relaxed. There are more traps to get into than with `unique_ptr`. And it's of course more expensive to use. But still, if you need shared ownership, that's the way to go.