# How to feed a shared_ptr to a template function that shall add various data types to a vector?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66382752/how-can-i-copy-a-unique-ptr-so-it-does-not-lose-possession) it was suggested to use `std::shared_ptr` instead of `std::unique_ptr`. However I am not able to make this work when feeding this shared pointer to my function:

```
 std::vector<std::unique_ptr<segment>> v3;

    //VERSION 5:
    auto myLine2 = std::make_shared<Line>(start, end);
    add_segment(v3, myLine2);
```

Here's the new implementation of the function:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
inline void add_segment(T1 & v, T2& line_or_circle)
{
    v.emplace_back(std::move(line_or_circle));
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "move" the thing inside a `shared_ptr` into an instance of a `unique_ptr`. If you could, all kinds of problems would occur as a result of two different smart pointers trying to delete the thing inside it when they get released.

Instead, just delcare your vector as :

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<segment>> v3;
```

And then, you really don't need move semantics after that:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
inline void add_segment(T1 & v, T2& line_or_circle)
{
    v.emplace_back(line_or_circle);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @selbie. This works. Sometimes I am so blind to see the almost obvious :D Answer up-voted.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure you willing to share the ownership of the Line or not. But I expect you would like to have a vector holding unique pointers. So when your vector is destroyed it cleans up everything. If your vector, again, if your vector is responsible for the life cycle of lines. Check this:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
inline void add_segment(T1 &v, std::unique_ptr<T2> line_or_circle)
{
    v.emplace_back(std::move(line_or_circle));
}

struct Line
{
    Line(int s, int e)
    {
        start = s;
        end = e;
    }
    int start;
    int end;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Line>> v3;

    auto myLine2 = std::make_unique<Line>(1, 5);
    add_segment(v3, std::move(myLine2));
}
```

Comment: That's what the OP had in the original (linked) question, in which the usage of `shared_ptr` was suggested.

Comment: Thank you Oussama Ben Ghorbel. @t.niese is correct. I had this in my previous implementation which however did not allow adding twice the same object to my vector due to the unique-ness of these objects. ```std::shared_ptr``` finally allows feeding twice the same object to my vector. I still would prefer a unique vector but as it seems the vector must have the same memory management as its data (which appears to be logical if I think about it).

Answer (score -1):

Can you post an error message at least?
Or produce enough code so that this is easily reproducible.

From what I can tell, I don't believe you are using `std::vector::emplace_back` correctly. `emplace_back` forwards parameters to the constructor of type `std::unique_ptr<segment>`. But `line` type does not match `std::unique_ptr<segment>`  type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. line is a derived class from the virtual class segment. When I follow the advice of the answer above it works fine.